# Locust giving "HTTPError('404 Client Error: Not Found for url:

Tags: python, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

I have a react web application, i want to do load testing on it using locust, on these 2 URL. (Homepage & Privacy Policy page). for homepage, it is working but for privacy page, it is giving "HTTPError('404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://xxx/privacy-policy/') " error. when I am hitting these URL on browser both URL open & not giving any error. Why Locust giving this error.

this is my code -

```
    import time
    from locust import HttpUser, task, constant

    class CreateLead(HttpUser):
    host = "https://xxx"
    wait_time = constant(0)

   @task
   def loadtest(self):
       self.client.get("/")
       time.sleep(1)

       self.client.get("/privacy-policy")
       time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Check your server logs

Comment: any solution for the above?